# Z3 will not case split on hand-crafted data types

Tags: z3, theorem-proving

I have defined my own booleans, called `boolean` is SMT2, and the AND function `boolean_and` over them.
My conjecture is that AND is commutative:

```
(declare-sort boolean)
(declare-const sk_x boolean)
(declare-const sk_y boolean)
(declare-const boolean_false boolean)
(declare-const boolean_true boolean)
(declare-fun boolean_and (boolean boolean) boolean)

;; axiomatize booleans: false /= true and every bool is true or false
(assert (forall ((x boolean)) (or (= x boolean_false)
                                  (= x boolean_true))))

(assert (not (= boolean_false boolean_true)))

;; definition of AND
(assert (forall ((a boolean)) (= (boolean_and boolean_false a) boolean_false)))
(assert (forall ((a boolean)) (= (boolean_and boolean_true a) a)))

;; try to prove that AND is commutative
(assert (not (= (boolean_and sk_x sk_y)
                (boolean_and sk_y sk_x))))

(check-sat)
```

However, z3 reports unknown on this problem after a while, even though I
thought it should be able to use my case split assertions on the skolemised
variables `sk_x` and `sk_y`.

Curiously, if I remove my boolean axiomatization and replace it with
`declare-datatypes`, z3 will report `unsat`:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((boolean (boolean_true) (boolean_false))))

(declare-const sk_x boolean)
(declare-const sk_y boolean)
(declare-fun boolean_and (boolean boolean) boolean)

(assert (forall ((a boolean)) (= (boolean_and boolean_false a) boolean_false)))
(assert (forall ((a boolean)) (= (boolean_and boolean_true a) a)))

(assert (not (= (boolean_and sk_x sk_y)
                (boolean_and sk_y sk_x))))

(check-sat)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get z3 to case split using my axiomatization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. The official release (v4.3.1) may fail on problems containing cardinality constraints such as

```
(assert (forall ((x boolean)) (or (= x boolean_false)
                                  (= x boolean_true))))
```

This constraint is asserting that the uninterpreted sort `boolean` has at most two elements.
I fixed this problem. The fix is already available in the `unstable` branch.
[Here](http://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20the%20unstable%20%28working-in-progress%29%20branch&referringTitle=Documentation) are some instructions on how to compile the `unstable` branch.
Tomorrow, the [nightly builds](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/blog/2013/02/15/precompiled.html) will also contain this fix.

Comment: Thank you! I'll rebuild tomorrow then.